# problema python TypeError: empleado() takes no arguments

Tags: python

```
class persona():
  def _init_(self, nombre, edad, residencia):      
    self.nombre=nombre
    self.edad=edad
    self.residencia=residencia

  def descripcion(self):
    print("nombre: ", self.nombre, "edad: ", self.edad, "residencia", self.residencia)

class empleado(persona):
  def _init_(self, salario, antiguedad, nombreEmpleado, resideciaEmpleado):
    super()._init_("jose", 23, "nicaragua") 
    self.salario=salario
    self.antiguedad=antiguedad

  def descripcion(self): 
    super().descripcion()
    print("salario: ", self.salario, "antiguedad: ", self.antiguedad)

jose=empleado(1500,15, "jose", 23, "nicaragua")
jose.descripcion() #no puede tener la herecia de descripcion porque esta en empleado

print(isinstance(jose, empleado))
```

Comment: Por favor, **sobre todo en el lenguaje `python`**, el correcto formateo del código es **muy** importante. Revisa que esté correcto; si es necesario, pulsa en [edit] la pregunta y corrige lo que esté mal. Un saludo.

Comment: typo: cambia `_init_` a `__init__`

Answer (score 2):

Tu código tiene dos errores:

Error 1. `__init__`  tiene que tener doble barra abaja antes y después de "init". Solo pusiste una barraba baja en ambos "init".

Error 2. `jose=empleado(1500,15, "jose", 23, "nicaragua")`   esta pasando 5 argumentos, pero tu objeto solo puede recibir 4 argumentos..... lo correcto sería algo como:
`jose=empleado(1500,15, "jose", "nicaragua")`